# Sending email to myself through GAS stays in gmail sent box and not in inbox

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I have a script that manipulates data on a sheet (based on other sheets updated throughout the day) that is run once a day. I would like to send myself an email (`MailApp.sendEmail`) if certain conditions are met. I have the script, the email is sent -- the problem is that I use gmail and since I am sending the message to myself it only appears in the sent box and not in the inbox.

I even tried to send it to another account that forwards it back to me but the result is the same. Unfortunately the filter actions available in gmail only include removing something from the inbox (archiving) and not moving to the inbox.

Any suggestions how I can get the mail sent to myself appear in the inbox so I actually notice it?

Comment: I had the same issue. I don't know all the details yet but it seems possible because in other flows I can successfully send emails to myself. I included another sheet in the script. This solved it. I think it has something to do with sharing, but it seems indeed to be weird.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how immediate you need to see the result and how frequent you want these emails sent, one solution is to send them to a Google Group to which you are the only member and have that set to send you a digest email.

This is how I handle quite a few reporting scripts. It also avoids an inbox full and makes it straightforward to apply a gmail filter to.

It also makes it straightforward to notify team members when the team maintaining scripts grows.